# Прогнозирования вычисляемых логических значений

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Вопрос- какая библиотека и какой алгоритм лучше подходит для прогнозирования вычисляемых логических значений? Что лучше использовать Machine или Deep Learning, etc?

Описание задачи для пояснения сути вопросов. 
1) За N дней есть данные по стоимости акций AMD в ниже перечисленном формате

```
Date - дата дня торгов
Open - цена на момент открытия дня 
High - максимальная цена внутри дня
Low - минимальная цена внутри дня 
Close - цена на момент закрытия дня 
Volume - объем торгов внутри дня 
OHOL - вычисляемое булевое значение для текущего дня, которое имеет значение true если (High - Open) >= (Open - Low) и значение false в остальных случаях.
```

На основе имеющихся данных нужно спрогнозировать с вероятностью >80% значение  OHOL на следующий день. Для данных приведенных ниже, нужно спрогнозировать значение столбца OHOL (true или false) на 10 февраля.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Источник (https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMD/)

Comment: Либа - на выбор, архитектура - начните с FFNN, dl подмножество ml. Ваша задача относится к задачам предсказания временных рядов. Читайте на эту тему, слишком обще у вас написан вопрос

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev Конкретизировал задачу и привел данные в качестве примера.

Answer (score 2):

Как вы думаете, если кто-то умеет предугадывать тенденцию роста акций с точностью 80% он будет сидеть на SO и делиться этими знаниями со всеми желающими, или будет рубить бабки на бирже? :-)

А вот сама ваша задача может быть решена различными методами, относящимися к классу "обучения с учителем". Или -  комбинацией этих методов. Если бы мне потребовалось решать подобную задачу (не достижения фантастических 80% вероятности, а просто двухклассовой диагностики) то я бы для начала использовал метод анализа временных рядов, например - многомерную ARIMA модель. Или попробовал бы применить метод деревьев решений (или лучше - случайного леса). Можно было бы попробовать использовать нейросети типа LSTM (кстати - весьма часто используется для различного рода "прогнозирования" именно на финансовых рынках и описаний этих попыток  в сети - предостаточно).

Многие реализации методов машинного обучения собраны в библиотеке Skikit-learn, а использования нейросетевых подходов - в Tensorflow. Экспериментируйте.

Comment: Вопрос, а что лучше для конкретной задачи ARIMA или LSTM? и почему? коротко плиз если можно

Comment: Если коротко - то для каждого конкретного случая надо экспериментировать и анализировать.  Кстати, многомерная ARIMA и LSTM не так уж сильно между собой отличаются.